# UISearchController results TableViewController doesn't clear results when UISearchBar is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm not great at iOS development and stuck on a simple problem.

I'm trying to create a UISearchController that has an empty message in the backgroundView of the results tableView when it's first launched or when the UISearchBar is empty (whether from backspacing, tapping the x to clear the field, or cancelling out of the UISearchBar).

I've accomplished adding the empty message when the UISearchBar is first focused, but after search has occurred, old search results are still in the results table view after I cancel out of search and when I empty the UISearchBar.

I think this has always been the case, but I haven't been seeing the old results previously, whereas now I set `searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false` to be able to see the background when the controller is first launched.

I've searched pretty extensively and just can't figure out how to clear the old results.

My whole results TableViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Mapbox

class LocationSearchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MGLMapView? = nil

    // This somehow connects and pleases the delegate
    var handleMapSearchDelegate: HandleMapSearch? = nil

    // Address formatting, not entirely sure what this is doing
    func parseAddress(selectedItem: MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }
}

// Extension with UISearchResultsUpdating delegate protocols
extension LocationSearchTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        // This unhides the results view so it's visible when the field is focused
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false

        // Get searchbar text and make query
        guard let _ = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        if searchBarText == "" {
//            searchResults.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

// Extension with all UITableViewDataSource methods grouped together
extension LocationSearchTableViewController {

    // Create rows based on number of returning items
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if matchingItems.count == 0 {
            setEmptyMessage()
        } else {
            restore()
        }


        return matchingItems.count
    }


    // Populate cells
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)

        return cell
    }
}

// Groups UITableViewDelegate methods together
extension LocationSearchTableViewController {

    // Function that fires on tapping a row
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Assign placemark value (coordinates)
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark


        // Delegate function that passes placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPin(placemark: selectedItem)

        // Dismiss searchController
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTableViewController {

    func setEmptyMessage() {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: rect)
        messageLabel.text = "Empty"
        messageLabel.textColor = .black
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 15)
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel
        //            self.tableView.backgroundView?.isHidden = false
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = Colors.black1
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }

    func restore() {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    }
}
```

And the relevant (I think) UISearchBar code from the main ViewController which implements the UISearchController:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        if let navigationController = navigationController { // this unwraps navigation controller
            navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                self.placeholderView.alpha = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happened when you do this ?
 if searchBarText == "" {
//            searchResults.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: you need to clear your dataArray .. and call reloadData()

Comment: Cool, I’ll try that! Where’s the appropriate place to do so?

Comment: Hello are you there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the method you need to clear your dataArray .. and call `reloadData()` on your `tableView`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      if searchText.isEmpty {

                searchResults.removeAll()
                tableView.reloadData()

      }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm... since the the UISearchBar is in a separate VC than the table results, I get an error saying both searchResults and tableView are unresolved identifiers.

Comment: `updateSearchResults` when did this function called ?

Comment: Thanks! This solved a good chunk of the problem. I had some deeper issues with managing the search query and latency I addressed which also helped solve some of the buggy behavior.